# Animation which involves a spherical floating robot and a little girl

Tags: story-identification, robots, animation

I've been trying to find this video forever and the only way I can remember is that it was an anime music video which was on one of those dance machines in an arcade but here is the description:

A little girl finds a spherical floating robot that is a blue color and a single eye which can shoot lasers. She ends up befriending said robot but then she is chased by the same robots which look the same as her new friend but they are black with a red eye (I guess to signify they were evil).

Then comes a sequence where the girl and the friendly spherical robot are traveling through a cave system to evade the evil robots. After reaching a split in the cave, the friendly robot gestures to the girl to go one way as it had a plan to evade the evil robots. The girl ends up going towards the exit of the cave. As she is making her way there, the friendly robot changes its color to black but has somewhat of a different colored eye (to show which one was the friendly robot) and leads the chasing robots down a different path.

The evil robots then go down the path but one of the evil robots who went last take a second take at the friendly robot and realize that it was an impostor to which all the rest come back to chase the friendly robot. The animation ends with the girl safely near a tree but then it shows the friendly robot broken and with a lined crack on its eye to signify it had sacrificed itself for its friend.

I hope someone can help me track down this animation as I've been wanting to see it again for so long and tried Google searching every possible thing. I've also attached a picture I made in Paint which shows what the robot(s) looked like.

[image: Robot ball from animation]

Comment: I'm curious about the arcade machine. Do you know what it was or have any details that would help to ID it? I've never seen one that had any lore as deep as this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to a quick internet search, this is the background animation for the music track "Canon-D" from the arcade game Pump It Up Exceed 2

YouTube video: [Canon D BGA for Pump it Up Exceed 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU93rtSGIug)

Similar question asked and answered on Reddit: [[Arcade machine] [2000-2010] Dance game music Video.](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/hf7pse/arcade_machine_20002010_dance_game_music_video/)

Comment: ^_^ I recognized that one right away based on the description.

Comment: Pump It Up Exceed 2. What a strange name.

Comment: Canon is a piece of classical music that everyone has heard by now but might not know the name. [The bit at 1:55 is particularly famous.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ptk_1Dc2iPY)

Comment: Yes, the music track is an arrangement of Pachelbel's [Canon in D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachelbel%27s_Canon).

Comment: Stupid feels...